# Device shows up in fastboot and recovery, but not in Android?

Tags: adb, usb, recovery-mode, fastboot

I have a Motorola Moto G 2014 device. The USB connection behaves very strangely.

- If I boot into fastboot, the device shows up **correctly** via `fastboot devices`
- If I boot into recovery, the device shows up **correctly** via `adb devices`
- If I boot into the OS (I've tried a whole bunch of different ROMs), the device **doesn't appear at all** via `adb devices`. It doesn't even appear as a valid USB device.

To debug it, I've run `lsusb -v` and checked the output.

In **fastboot** the device shows up like this:

```
Fastboot titan S:

Product ID: 0x2e80
Vendor ID: 0x22b8  (Motorola MDS)
Version: 1.00
Serial Number: [removed]
Speed: Up to 480 Mb/sec
Manufacturer: Motorola Inc.
Location ID: 0x14100000 / 21
Current Available (mA): 500
Current Required (mA): 500
Extra Operating Current (mA): 0
```

In **recovery** the device shows up like this:

```
Moto G 2014:

Product ID: 0x2e76
Vendor ID: 0x22b8  (Motorola MDS)
Version: 2.28
Serial Number: [removed]
Speed: Up to 480 Mb/sec
Manufacturer: Motorola
Location ID: 0x14100000 / 29
Current Available (mA): 500
Current Required (mA): 500
Extra Operating Current (mA): 0
```

**But once I boot into the OS... nothing**! `adb devices` shows nothing.

I've enabled USB Debugging, I've tried switching the USB mode from/to MTP and so on. In my mind, though, none of that's relevant if the device doesn't even appear over USB!

What's frustrating to me is that I can't determine whether it's a software or a hardware error. If it's a software error, why don't *any* of the ROMs I've tried work?

I'm assuming it's a hardware error (I bought the device used and it has a cracked screen), but how could it be that the device works properly in fastboot and recovery mode if there's a hardware issue with the USB?

Comment: This is the grand daddy of ADB errors. Looking at these  device logs- are they meant to be different?

Comment: @DanBrown I think it's OK that they're different -- my guess is that it's a different USB driver on the device side that's used depending on whether the device is in fastboot or recovery. The trouble is it doesn't appear as a valid USB device once I've booted into the OS.

Comment: Hmmmmm, it might be worth a full stock reflash from fastboot. I know you've probably tried that already, but no harm no foul, eh?

Comment: @DanBrown Yeah, I've tried several stock builds. Maybe I'll try it again! I'm mostly convinced it's a hardware issue at this point, I'd just love for some clue as to what could trigger this type of behaviour from a hardware perspective. USB is obviously still functional, just not in certain situations.

Comment: Does it charge fine? Oh! Does it work with any other computer, or is it just yours?

Comment: @DanBrown Charges totally fine, yep. And again, USB works fine in fastboot and recovery, but not in any ROM I've tried. I mean, as far as I understand it, USB is only 4 pins! So that implies that if it works in fastboot and recovery that it's not a hardware issue. But then none of the ROMs fix anything! I've tried on both a Windows and Mac. The Mac just shows nothing, and the Windows machine will sometimes says the USB device is invalid.

Comment: I am clueless then. It's definitely a hardware issue with the phone. I would called it software, but you've even tried with stock....

Comment: @DanBrown Appreciate the feedback! I think the phone's just a dud, unfortunately. I just wish I understood USB a bit more at the hardware level so I could try soldering around in there in hopes of fixing something :)

Comment: No problem man. Sorry we cannot reach a resolution :(